# How to use Stagefright with a predefined buffer for decoded frames?

Tags: android, video, rendering, stagefright

I would like to create a simple Android application which would play video file, but it would replace one color (of my choice) in the displayed frame with another color (of my choice). I assume there is some interface/API in which application could provide URI and buffer-for-decoded-frames to Stagefright, so the application is allowed to modify the display buffer before it is shown on the screen.

Can anybody point me to the API or to the way how to instruct Stagefright to decode frames into an already predefined buffer?

Thank you.